# Regular expression for validating decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function validateDecimal(number,maxDigits)
{
    eval("var stringvar=/^[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]{0,"+maxDigits+"})|([0-9]+)$/");

    return stringvar.test(number);
}
```

I wrote above function to validate decimal numbers. The variable 'maxDigits' uses to specify the number of digits in fractional part and 'number' as the value to be validated. But it returned 'true' when I tried with a numeric value followed by a character for eg: 24y. Can anyone help me to figure out my mistake.

Comment: You don't need to use `eval` here, the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor can take a string as an argument.

Comment: Your anchors are misaligned, you want `^a$|^b$` or `^(a|b)$` not `^a|b$` - unless you specifically want to permit anything after the number in the case of a decimal point, or before the number without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going into the regex, I think the problem in your code is that you should escape the special character twice. Since you're putting it all inside a string, a single backslash is escaped by the string parsing.

I think this should work:

```
eval("var stringvar=/^[-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]{0,"+maxDigits+"})|([0-9]+)$/");
```

Comment: Yeah seems like you where correct. I am not exactly a Javascript person, this is the first time I've seen something like that. I was confused a bit cos the OP's regex seemed valid to me in the first place. I will leave my answer just as an alternative solution, but +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But I don't get the problem. I used '\' to escape the character '.' then what is the need to escape '\' itself.

Comment: The string literal that you pass to eval is just like any other string literal. This means that a single backslash is used to escape characters that have a special meaning in a string. When the expression is evaluated, then you're left with a regex, in which you also need a backslash to escape characters that have special meaning for a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this one and it worked for me: `^[+-]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,5})?$`.

In my case I made a minor modification, you seem to be matching either a decimal number or else a whole number. In my case, I modified the regular expression to take a whole number with an optional decimal section.

As is, the regular expression will match values like: `.222`, `23.22222` but not `4d.22222`, `33.333333`, etc.

```
var n1 = "4.33254";
var n2 = "4d.55";

eval("var stringvar=/^[+-]?[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]{0,5})?$/");
alert(stringvar.test(n1));
alert(stringvar.test(n2));
```

Yielded: `true` and `false` respectively.

Comment: I tried the value 2s with this regular expression but the result was true.

Comment: what about 4d55? I think the problem is the unescaped '.'. see my answer below.

Comment: @shinod: Yes you do have a point, which has been explained by *davidrac*. I have fixed my answer, it should now work, as per *davidrac*'s suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression would validate a number with maxDigits of decimals:
`^[-+]?[0-9]*.[0-9]{10}$`.  This will validate it to 10 decimal places.

Implementing that into JavaScript would look like:
`eval("var stringvar=^[-+]?[0-9]*.[0-9]{" + maxDigits + "}$");`, or thereabouts.

Comment: I'm not able to check my JavaScript at this time, but I can confirm that that expression will work with an expected number of decimal places.